# Changing Password to connect the Server in Apache Ignite

Tags: java, caching, server, ignite

I am running apache ignite 2.8.0.
Using java thin client i am able to connect the server with default username = 'ignite' and password = 'ignite'.

```
ClientConfiguration cfg = new ClientConfiguration()
        .setAddresses("127.0.0.1:10800")
        .setUserName("ignite")
        .setUserPassword("ignite");
```

Now i have two question:

- 1. My java thin client terminated immediately, how can i keep alive my thin client?
- 2. How to change the default username = 'ignite' and password = 'ignite' to my wish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Avoid closing it? Why would it terminate otherwise? Do you get any error messages?
2. Execute the following SQL command: `ALTER USER "ignite" WITH PASSWORD 'newPassword';`

Comment: No, i am not forcefully terminating

Comment: can you add sample code ALTER USER "ignite" WITH PASSWORD 'newPassword'; with this?

Comment: `bin/sqlline.sh` `!connect jdbc:ignite:thin://localhost` `ignite` `ignite` `ALTER USER "ignite" WITH PASSWORD 'newPassword';`